# Attribute Routing With Parameters - Anchor Tag Helper Appending Route-Id Value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have setup the "basic" routes in Startup.cs with nothing out of the ordinary (one for the standard routing and another for areas).  They are below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "Areas",
       pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Now, with these two, I'm able to navigate (albeit manually) to the routes I want.  Below is an attribute route I have on an action:

```
[Route("Admin/Artists/{artistId:int}/Albums")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Albums(int artistId)
{
    var albums = await Mediatr.Send(new GetAlbumsForArtistRequest { ArtistId = artistId });

    return View(albums);
}
```

I can successfully browse to that route *(albeit manually)* and my view appears.  I then try using the anchor tag helper:

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Artists" asp-action="Albums" asp-route-artist-id="@ViewData["ArtistId"]" class="btn btn-info">Albums</a>
```

The URL that is generated is not correct (and throws an exception as this route is not defined):

```
/Admin/Artists/Albums
```

When the correct URL should be:

```
/Admin/Artists/558/Albums
```

I have tried finding any help on the [Anchor Tag Helper documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1), but it was no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the correct URL should be: `/Admin/Artists/558/Albums`

In your code, we can find that you specify `asp-route-artist-id="@ViewData["ArtistId"]"` for Anchor Tag Helper, which cause the issue.

Please remove `-` between `artist` and `id`, it should be `asp-route-artistid`.

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Are our Startup.Configure methods the same?  Maybe that's what I have wrong because after removing the hyphen, it still doesn't work for me:

Comment: `Are our Startup.Configure methods the same?` Yes, I did same to add endpoints for controller actions.

Comment: You were absolutely correct.  I created a new controller as a test and it worked like a charm.  My original controller must have something else going on because it doesn't work there.  Thank you for pointing out the issue.